# How to link main with .h . c files

Tags: c, list

I'm working on dubble linked list. Worked out the .h & .c files.

```
//.h -file

typedef struct Data_t{
        int d_sz;
        void * data;
    }data_t, * data_ptr_t;

    typedef struct List_t{
            int index;
            struct List_t * next;
            struct List_t * prev;
            data_t * d;
    }list_t, * list_ptr_t;
```

// .c file

```
/**
 * Inserts a new element containing 'data' in 'list' at position 'index'  and returns a pointer to the new list. 
 * If 'index' is 0 or negative, the element is inserted at the start of 'list'. 
 * If 'index' is bigger than the number of elements in 'list', the element is inserted at the end of 'list'.
 */
list_ptr_t list_insert_at_index( list_ptr_t list, data_ptr_t data, int index){

                            // add data to newlist
        return newlist;
    }
```

// .main

```
int i;
    int value;


    data_ptr_t h;
    list_ptr_t l;
    printf("Enter a value:");
    scanf("%d",&value);

    l = list_insert_at_index( ? , ?, 0);
```

// How to get the function working? What to exactly to this function? It has to be this function only.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please read the [FAQ].  The question should not be vandalized after you've received answers (and by dropping most of the code, you have vandalized your own question).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your main you need to

```
#include "YOUR.H"
```

Where YOUR.H is the name of the .h file you show at the top of your post.

This will give YOUR.MAIN.C a "promise" that when you compile/link the given data types and functions will be present. It gives enough data to prepare main to link with YOUR.c

When you compile be sure to pass in all three files to the compiler. It should work. More details of what you have tried would help get a more specific answer.

Answer (score 2):

If the name of your .h and .c files are `test.c` and `test.h` for example, put this at the top of your main.cpp

```
#include "test.h"
```

Then you can use all the functions you defined in the header file